# How to inspect current values of parameters of theorem style?

Tags: theorems

I'd like to alter the plain theorem style so it uses `\slshape` instead of `\itshape`. I know I can define my own style via `\newtheoremstyle` but I don't know how to inspect (possibly in runtime) the current values of the parameters of the style so I can just change what I need and leave the rest alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the easiest way to do it is `\def \th@plain {\slshape}` or better: `\def \th@slanted {\slshape}` and then use `\theoremstyle{slanted}`. There is/was also macro `\theorembodyfont` which is intended for this, but I'm not sure in what package it is located.

Answer (score 3):

You can see it in the `amsthm.sty` file sitting in somewhere in your distro

```
\thm@style{plain}
\newtoks\thm@bodyfont  \thm@bodyfont{\itshape}
\newtoks\thm@headfont  \thm@headfont{\bfseries}
\newtoks\thm@notefont  \thm@notefont{}
\newtoks\thm@headpunct \thm@headpunct{.}
\newskip\thm@preskip \newskip\thm@postskip
\def\thm@space@setup{%
  \thm@preskip=\topsep \thm@postskip=\thm@preskip
}
```

This is kind of the bowel movement version of the user-level and much clearer `\newtheoremstyle` command. I don't recommend fiddling with the already defined styles but if we were doing it from scracth we would have (didn't check though)

```
\newtheoremstyle{plain}{\topsep}{\topsep}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{.}{.5em}{}%
```

Comment: I would think that inheritance between styles or at least exposing the defaults is standard functionality. What if I later use some package which alters the definitions? Then the hard-coded values of parameters don't make sense. And for your values, somewhere I've seen 5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt and somewhere .5em for space parameter.

Comment: @user87690 Most packages (the good ones) always offer a switch for keeping the originals.